# I keep getting NameError: name 'root' is not defined in Tkinter when running a registration application

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting :
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
when running the code:

```
    import sqlite3
from tkinter import *

def register():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    root.title("Register App 1.0")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    myLabelEntry = Label(root, text="Register Project", font=("Arial", 25), bg = "grey", width = "300")
    myLabelEntry.pack()

    beginLabel = Label(root, text="To Begin Registration, Click Y:", font=("Arial", 15))
    beginLabel.pack()

    beginButton = Button(root, text="Y", font=("Arial", 15))
    beginButton.pack()

register()


root.mainloop()
```

I have ran code similar to this before which seemed to work however that didn't involve many functions if any at all. Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: either put `root.mainloop()` inside the function or use `global root` at the start of the function (name `root` is only defined locally inside the function), also don't use `*` when importing

Comment: I dont see any reason why `root.mainloop()` should be outside `register()` wen `root` is inside it

Comment: Thank you all! I used global root and it worked! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root is a variable created inside the register() function, so it can't use it outside of it.
To solve it, just create the window outside the function or make a variable global.

```
global root
```

or

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.title("Register App 1.0")
root.resizable(False, False)
def register():
    #program
register()
root.mainloop()
```